# how to auto submit a form after input field automatic change?

Tags: javascript, php

i have for(loop) form in PHP
-every time the input field getting a new value,and i need to submit this form with the new value.

```
$ar=array('0','1','2','3');
$co=count($ar);

static $i1;
static $i2;
for($i1=0;$i1<$co;$i1++){
$p1=$ar[$i1];

for($i2=0;$i2<$co;$i2++){
 $p2=$ar[$i2];

 $pass=$p1.$p2;
 echo $pass;

 $break="<form name=\"ffo\" id=\"forms\" method=\"POST\" action=\"login.php\">";
 $break.="<input type=\"text\" name=\"login\" value=\"login\" />";
 $break.="<input id=\"p\" type=\"text\" name=\"pass\" value=\"$pass\" />";
 $break.="<input class=\"ss\" type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"login\"/>";
 $break.="</form>";

 echo $break;
 }
}
```

i have tried this javascript code but i keep getting only the first value from the (for) > 00, because in the action(target) page i have (header) back if the [pass] not right.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.ss').click();
 });
```

the form should submit 00,01,02,03,04,10,11....etc

Comment: you can write jquery's change() function to detect value chane in input field and submit the form through jquery/js

Comment: tried it, didn't detect any changes

Comment: show us how did you tried it, may be you've written something wrong in it

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
$('.ss').click();
$('#forms').submit();
 });